# Quickfix - Set sequence number in Python

Tags: python, swig, quickfix, python-bindings

I use the Python bindings that come with [Quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) and I'd like to set the sequence number through it (see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800354/quickfix-syncing-sequence-numbers)). How can I do this?

I found the following in the [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) bindings:

```
class Session(_object):
    # ...
    def setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(self, *args): return _quickfix.Session_setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(self, *args)
    # ...
```

It requires two parameters: a `Session` object and an `int` sequence number.
 How can I get the `Session` object?
Or is there another method of setting the sequence number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are you have a reference to a [`SessionID`](http://FIX%3a%3aSessionID) object associated with the session (for example, by caching the session-Id given to you in the `Application.onCreate` method when the session is created)  . In this case, you can use the `Session.lookupSession` method to look the session up from the `SessionID`. If you don't, you can construct a `SessionID`  first from the BeginString, SenderCompID and TargetCompID of the session you are interested in.

Sorry, but I don't know Python -  so I can't provide you with an example.

Comment: I was able to get the session object this way by using the following in Python: `session = fix.Session.lookupSession(sessionID)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, i got it...
need to figure out how to read from log but in

```py
def onCreate(self, sessionID):
    self.sessionID = sessionID 
    self.session = fix.Session.lookupSession(self.sessionID)
    print self.session
    n = 14088
    self.session.setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(n)
```

this worked