# Sequence number and gaps?

Tags: java, quickfix

Can anyone tell me working of sequence numbers and how sequence gaps are recovered in quickfix/j ?

Comment: No. Ask specific question with code examples.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Maybe not very well formulated but it seems to be a valid question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800354/quickfix-syncing-sequence-numbers

Comment: @Nikita - I was asking about the concept of using sequence number in quick fix, not asking the code - You interpreted wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it doesn't. It assumes

- You are using a reliable transport such as TCP
- Your routers will ensure sequences are delivered in order without drop outs.

If you see a gap in the sequence numbers something fairly major must have gone wrong and you need to flag this to a user/support staff. It's not something it can recover from automatically.