# Serious Error :Message sequence number 1 expecting 326 while resubmitting a report using Quicfixj

Tags: fix-protocol

I am trying to resubmit a report using quickfixj ,on first submission the report is submitted successfully  but when i try to re submit the same report, i get error saying: Serious Error :Message sequence number 1 expecting 326 while resubmitting ,In the event logs I could find session is created called,to admin and from admin called.After that onlogout is called giving the above error with msgtype =2 
Is this an error on client side or the server side?pls suggest.I have also tried using resetmessagesequence=Y and resetonlogout=Y in the config file on default level .But I get the same errors on resubmitting the report .Please advise

Comment: Sounds like you should set resetmessagesequence=N and resetonlogout=N also message type 2 is a resend request probably from the server. You need to look at the server side sequence number policy

Comment: I have investigated and found that on every logon the client side message sequence number starts with 1 and on server side its not happening that's why its expecting 326.I tried adding the above mentioned flags to N still the message sequence number is sent as 1 and increments .pls suggest what should I do to sync the sequence numbers on both side

Comment: Per [quickfixj config](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html#Miscellaneous) you could try ForceResync -> When logout response contains "expecting XXX", the sequence numbers are forcibly resynchronized.

Comment: Or like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800354/quickfix-syncing-sequence-numbers) from FIX 4.1 onwards, the Logon message (A) contains a tag ResetSeqNumFlag (141). Setting it to 'Y' "indicates that both sides of the FIX session should reset sequence numbers."

Comment: Thank you rupweb could you pls tell me how do I set the ResetSeqNumFlag to Y in logon.I am using sendtotarget (message ,sessionid)function of quickfixj .I tried using message.set field(reset sequence(true)).But its not sending the rest flag in logon .

Comment: As a guess you put it in the config file